# tracking upload progress of multiple file uploads using multipart/body web request

Tags: c#, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I'm using HttpWebRequest to upload files to the server. The request sends 2 files to the server, a video file and an image file. I'm trying to track the progress of entire progress but the issue is, the progress log runs separately for each file upload. I want the progress to show only once for both the uploads but I can't quite figure out how to do it. Here's my client side code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        fields.Add("username", username);

        HttpWebRequest hr = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        hr.Timeout = 500000;
        string bound = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        hr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + bound;
        hr.Method = "POST";
        hr.KeepAlive = true;
        hr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        byte[] boundBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + bound + "\r\n");
        string formDataTemplate = "\r\n--" + bound + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";

        Stream s = hr.GetRequestStreamWithTimeout(1000000);

        foreach (string key in fields.Keys)
        {
            byte[] formItemBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                string.Format(formDataTemplate, key, fields[key]));
            s.Write(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length);
        }

        s.Write(boundBytes, 0, boundBytes.Length);

        string headerTemplate =
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

        List<string> files = new List<string> { fileUrl, thumbUrl };
        List<string> type = new List<string> { "video", "thumb" };

        int count = 0;
        foreach (string f in files)
        {
            var m = Path.GetFileName(f);
            var t = type[count];
            var j = string.Format(headerTemplate, t, m);
            byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                string.Format(headerTemplate, type[count], Path.GetFileName(f)));

            s.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            int bytesRead = 0;
            long bytesSoFar = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                bytesSoFar += bytesRead;
                s.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("sending file data {0:0.000}%", (bytesSoFar * 100.0f) / fs.Length));

            }

            s.Write(boundBytes, 0, boundBytes.Length);
            fs.Close();

            count += 1;
        }

        s.Close();

        string respString = "";
        hr.BeginGetResponse((IAsyncResult res) =>
        {
            WebResponse resp = ((HttpWebRequest)res.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(res);

            StreamReader respReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            respString = respReader.ReadToEnd();
            resp.Close();
            resp = null;
        }, hr);

        while (!hr.HaveResponse)
        {
            Console.Write("hiya bob!");
            Thread.Sleep(150);
        }

        Console.Write(respString);
        hr = null;
```

How do I combine the progress log for both uploads into a single log? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to calculate the total number of bytes you need to send before doing any work:

```
// Calculate the total size to upload before starting work
long totalToUpload = 0;
foreach (var f in files)
{
    totalToUpload += (new FileInfo(f)).Length;
}
```

Then keep track of the total number of bytes sent in any file, and use that in your calculation of progress:

```
int count = 0;
long bytesSoFar = 0;

foreach (string f in files)
{
    // ... Your existing work ...

    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        bytesSoFar += bytesRead;
        // Make sure to only write the number of bytes read from the file
        s.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        // Console.WriteLine takes a string.Format() style string
        Console.WriteLine("sending file data {0:0.000}%", (bytesSoFar * 100.0f) / totalToUpload);
    }
```

Comment: Cool. This could work. I will rate ur answer and come back to mark it as answered if I get it to work. Thanks! :)

Comment: Shouldn't bytesSoFar include the bytes of the previous file upload? The progress bar goes from 0 to 96% for the first file upload and starts at 0 and goes till 3.426% for the second upload

Comment: I think I need to define bytesSoFar outside the scope of the loop

Comment: Yes, it should.  You'll note I've moved `bytesSoFar` outside of the `foreach` loop so that it does.  Also, it's important to note that `s.Write(...)` should operate on the number in `bytesRead`, not `buffer.Length`.  They will be the same often, but almost always different on the last read from the file.